# WinForms - DataGridView - no cell selected

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

Is there a way to make a DataGridView have no cell selected? I notice even when it loses focus() it has a at least one active cell. Is there another mode that allows this? or some other trick?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

DataGridView.CurrentCell property can be used to clear the focus rectangle.

> You can set this property
>   (DataGridView.CurrentCell) to null to
>   temporarily remove the focus
>   rectangle, but when the control
>   receives focus and the value of this
>   property is null, it is automatically
>   set to the value of the
>   FirstDisplayedCell property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx

Answer (score 7):

I found that the `DataGridView.CurrentCell = null` didn't work for me when trying to get the requested behaviour.

What I ended up using was:

```
    private void dgvMyGrid_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvMyGrid.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            dgvMyGrid.SelectedRows[0].Selected = false;
        }

        dgvMyGrid.SelectionChanged += dgvMyGrid_SelectionChanged;
    }
```

It needed to be in the `DataBindingComplete` event handler.

Where you attach the `SelectionChanged` event handler doesn't affect the desired behaviour but I left it in the code snippet because I noticed for my needs at least it was better to only attach the handler after databinding, so that I avoid a selection changed event being raised for each item bound.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with setting the DataGridView.CurrentCell to null on the selection change event is that later events (like click) will not be hit.

The option that worked for me was to change the selection color to the grid color. The selection will therefore not be visible.

```
RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = BackgroundColor;
RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = ForeColor;
```

Comment: Your solution will not make a DataGridView with no cell selected. It's just appearence...

Answer (score 4):

I spent hours to find the solution for this problem. Do this:

1. Create a Form Project
2. Add a DataGridView with the name "DataGridView1"
3. Add the following code to your class Form1

   ```
   Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

   Dim dgvRow(17) As DataGridViewRow
   Dim i As Integer
   For i = 0 To dgvRow.Length - 1
       dgvRow(i) = New DataGridViewRow()
       dgvRow(i).Height = 16
       dgvRow(i).Selected = False
       dgvRow(i).ReadOnly = True
       DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgvRow(i))
       DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Selected = False
   Next
   End Sub
   ```

The importaint line of code is

```
    DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Selected = False
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem and I followed this way:

1. 'Initial active cell' cleared by dataGridView.ClearSelection().
2. Clear/Ignore the selection in the event handler, 'CellMouseClick' Event.

   ```
   void dataGridView_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)

   {

       DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;

       dgv.ClearSelection();

   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question and WinForms is superseded (but not for a long while still in our shop anyway), so this is still relevant to us and I suspect a few others too.

Instead of fiddling with the selection or `CurrentCell`, I found the implementation to simply change the row selection colours much more suitable for our needs.

In addition I no longer have to keep track of the old selected cell when losing focus nor have deal with the tricky issue when the grid is refreshed when not focus (like by a timer) and the old selected cell cannot be "restored" when focus is returned.

In addition to the solutions already posted above, we couldn't (didn't want to) inherit from the `DataGridView` control and instead opted to use composition. The code below shows the class used to implement the functionality, followed by code on how to use it to "attach" the behaviour to a DataGridView.

```
/// <summary>
/// Responsible for hiding the selection of a DataGridView row when the control loses focus.
/// </summary>
public class DataGridViewHideSelection : IDisposable
{
    private readonly DataGridView _dataGridView;

    private Color _alternatingRowSelectionBackColor = Color.Empty;
    private Color _alternatingRowSelectionForeColor = Color.Empty;
    private Color _rowSelectionBackColor = Color.Empty;
    private Color _rowSelectionForeColor = Color.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DataGridViewHideSelection"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dataGridView">The data grid view.</param>
    public DataGridViewHideSelection( DataGridView dataGridView )
    {
        if ( dataGridView == null )
            throw new ArgumentNullException( "dataGridView" );

        _dataGridView = dataGridView;
        _dataGridView.Enter += DataGridView_Enter;
        _dataGridView.Leave += DataGridView_Leave;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the Enter event of the DataGridView control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void DataGridView_Enter( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        // Restore original colour
        if ( _rowSelectionBackColor != Color.Empty )
            _dataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = _rowSelectionBackColor;

        if ( _rowSelectionForeColor != Color.Empty )
            _dataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = _rowSelectionForeColor;

        if ( _alternatingRowSelectionBackColor != Color.Empty )
            _dataGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = _alternatingRowSelectionBackColor;

        if ( _alternatingRowSelectionForeColor != Color.Empty )
            _dataGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = _alternatingRowSelectionForeColor;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the Leave event of the DataGridView control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void DataGridView_Leave( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        // Backup original colour
        _rowSelectionBackColor = _dataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor;
        _rowSelectionForeColor = _dataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor;
        _alternatingRowSelectionBackColor = _dataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor;
        _alternatingRowSelectionForeColor = _dataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor;

        // Change to "blend" in
        _dataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = _dataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
        _dataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = _dataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor;
        _dataGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = _dataGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
        _dataGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = _dataGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor;
    }

    #region IDisposable implementation (for root base class)

    private bool _disposed;

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Called by consumers.
    /// </remarks>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose( true );
        GC.SuppressFinalize( this );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes this instance, with an indication whether it is called from managed code or the GC's finalization of this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Overridden by inheritors.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="disposingFromManagedCode">if set to <c>true</c> disposing from managed code.</param>
    protected virtual void Dispose( Boolean disposingFromManagedCode )
    {
        if ( _disposed )
            return;

        // Clean up managed resources here
        if ( disposingFromManagedCode )
        {
            if ( _dataGridView != null )
            {
                _dataGridView.Enter -= DataGridView_Enter;
                _dataGridView.Leave -= DataGridView_Leave;
            }
        }

        // Clean up any unmanaged resources here

        // Signal disposal has been done.
        _disposed = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finalize an instance of the <see cref="DataGridViewHideSelection"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    ~DataGridViewHideSelection()
    {
        Dispose( false );
    }

    #endregion
}


/// <summary>
/// Extends data grid view capabilities with additional extension methods.
/// </summary>
public static class DataGridViewExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Attaches the hide selection behaviour to the specified DataGridView instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dataGridView">The data grid view.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">dataGridView</exception>
    public static DataGridViewHideSelection AttachHideSelectionBehaviour( this DataGridView dataGridView )
    {
        if ( dataGridView == null )
            throw new ArgumentNullException( "dataGridView" );

        return new DataGridViewHideSelection( dataGridView );
    }
}
```

**Usage:**
To use instantiate an instance of the DataGridViewHideSelection class and dispose of it when you don't need functionality any-more.

```
var hideSelection = new DataGridViewHideSelection( myGridView );

// ...

/// When no longer needed
hideSelection.Dispose();
```

Alternatively, you can use the convenient extension method `AttachHideSelectionBehaviour()` to make life a little easier.

```
myDataGrid.AttachHideSelectionBehaviour();
```

Maybe that's helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DataGridView.ClearSelection()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.clearselection(v=vs.110).aspx) whereever you want to clear the focus/selection (e.g. InitializeComponent, [Control.LostFocus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx), [Form.Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx)).