# how to prevent datagridview cell selection at form load

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

How to make a datagrid view cell not selected at form load for this

I have tried too much

my dgvproducts properties are `(readonly = false,selection mode = CellSelect)`

1) i have place this code in `form shown` event but that does not work for me ..

```
         dgvProducts.Clearselection();
```

2) I have place the above code in `databinding event` like the below..

```
     private void dgvProducts_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
     {
         //dgvProducts.ClearSelection();
         ((DataGridView)sender).ClearSelection();
     }
```

it does not work for me ...

3) i have placed similar code and i have added extra line to that in `form load event` but does not work for me ..

```
  dgvProducts.ClearSelection();
  dgvProducts.currentcell = null;
```

but this is not work for me ....

this is my form load code

```
      private void SellEquipment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            getProductDetails();
            dgvProducts.Columns[0].Visible = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < dgvProducts.Columns.Count; i++)
            if (dgvProducts.Columns[i] is DataGridViewImageColumn)
            {
                ((DataGridViewImageColumn)dgvProducts.Columns[i]).ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
                break;
            }
      }
```

and this is my getproductdetails code

```
   private void getProductDetails()
   {
        var products = from productlist in dbcontext.products
                       select new
                       {
                           productid = productlist.productId,
                           Name = productlist.Name,
                           Image = productlist.Image,
                           Description = productlist.Description,
                           Price = productlist.Price
                       };

        BindingProductsource.DataSource = products;
        dgvProducts.DataSource = BindingProductsource;
        dgvProducts.ClearSelection();         
   }
```

would any one pls help on this..

Many thanks...

Comment: check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341018/winforms-datagridview-no-cell-selected

Comment: DataGridView.CurrentCell = null i have already tried this....many thanks ..but it does not work for me ..

Comment: @Samich i have tried all those answers but it dint work for me ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285829/datagridview-how-to-focus-the-whole-row-instead-of-a-single-cell/331438#331438

Comment: @Stuart Dunkeld  sorry does not work ...

Comment: @errorcode105 did you set your SelectionMode to FullRowSelect?

Comment: @Stuart Dunkeld thats not my requirement  i want select single cell so i have set the property like this....selection mode = CellSelect;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try creating a new event OnShow and do this code:

```
    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count; i++)
                this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].Selected = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that overriding [`Form.OnShown()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onshown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as advised in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7336896/1497596) by @Mitja Bonca indeed worked for my purposes. However, I found that making use of [`DataGridView.ClearSelection()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxdf3ekh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) allowed me to achieve a leaner solution:

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    this.dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    base.OnShown(e);
}
```

Regarding the call to `base.OnShown()`, in its documentation Microsoft advises:

> **Notes to Inheritors**
>
> When overriding OnShown in a derived class, be sure to call the base
>   class's OnShown method so that registered delegates receive the event.